# OWASP Consider regenerating a new session upon successful authentication or privilege level change

Tags: session, owasp

On the OWASP web site one of their top ten items states that we should consider regenerating a new session upon successful authentication or privilege level change.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

One thing a co-worker has told me but I haven't tested is that when a user uses browser tabs each tab does not get it's own session, so I think that would negate the whole exercise.

Thanks,
Paul Speranza

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you are using, you would simply call something like session.invalidate() and then redirect which would create a new session.